# Rewrite URL variable after slash at the end of a URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm building w Wordpress site and I have to pass a get parameter in the URL string, my issue is that after trying all the usual rewrites I have found on here (I have no idea about rewrites) none seem to work, and yes I have the mod_rewrite enabled. The URL is like this www.mysite.com/staff/?staffid=12

How can I rewrote that to
www.mysite.com/staff/staffid/12/

Permalinks are already turned on etc also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've asked this question before, unfortunately nobody answered because everybody seems to hate .htaccess rewriting (not a popular thing) and there's no easy-to-follow guides online. Im especially interested in changing **?edit=** and **?updated=true** part if you edit post.

Comment: Once we get an answer to my question it should be pretty simple to change it for your needs. I suspect we have to target the index.php file within the redirect but I don't know if that will mess up Wordpress default permalink structure